# function prints out multiple correct outputs within for loop, doesn't print correctly outside of for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

My function is working correctly but it prints the output multiple times because it is in the for loop. When I try to take it out of the for loop it only prints the first digit multiple times.

my code:

```
myNum=4
iterationCount=3
doSummation=True

def printSomeNumbers(myNum,iterationCount,doSummation):

    for i in range(iterationCount):
        if (doSummation== False):
            print(myNum)
        else:
            counter= 0
            for i in range(iterationCount):
                counter+=myNum
                print(counter)          

printSomeNumbers(myNum,iterationCount,doSummation)
```

When I run this it outputs:

```
4
8
12
4
8
12
4
8
12
```

I want it to only output:

```
4
8
12
```

When I change the print indent like so:

```
else:
    counter= 0
    for i in range(iterationCount):
        counter+=myNum
    print(counter)
```

Or further to left, it outputs:

```
12
12
12
```

When doSummation is False, it is only supposed to output myNum the amount of times the value of iterationCount.

Comment: Why do you use two nested for loops, then?

Comment: I don't really understand. What exactly are you trying to implement (not how, but what)?

Comment: @Iguananaut Im only trying to make the second loop output the counter the amount of times of the value of iterationCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example which only prints it once. Like other comments suggested the nested for loop is causing it to print 3 times.

This prints normal:

```
def printSomeNumbers(myNum,iterationCount,doSummation):
  if doSummation:
    counter= 0
    for i in range(iterationCount):
        counter+=myNum
        print(counter)  
  else:
    for i in range(iterationCount):
      print(myNum)
```

Comment: Answer is updated to match the updated question, with implementation of `doSummation`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same code with some rearranging to hopefully fix it:

```
def printSomeNumbers(myNum,iterationCount,doSummation):

    if (doSummation== False):
        print(myNum)
    else:
        counter= 0
        for i in range(iterationCount):
            counter+=myNum
            print(counter)

printSomeNumbers(4,3,True)
print('...')
printSomeNumbers(4,3,False)
```

The output of this fixed code is:

```
4
8
12
...
4
```